# Facebook PHP SDK - Obtaining an access token automatically

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to connect to the Facebook Graph API using the PHP SDK and view recent posts of a business account.  BTW: I know there is a widget available for this task, but due to speed constraints, I would rather access the API and cache the response myself.

So I used my personal account to sign up at developers.facebook.com, created an app and obtained an AppId and AppSecret.  My question relates to obtaining an access token for use with the graph API using the PHP SDK.

The examples on the [getting started page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/5.0.0) shows how to obtain an access token by manually clicking a link and receiving a callback to my website.  I am not creating a public app as such, I don’t want a manual login because my script will be run periodically by the server.

In any case if I click the Log in with Facebook! link, I get the following message which I don't understand:

[image: Facebook Login]

The Twitter API provides automatic authentication but I cannot understand how to impliment this using Facebook.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I am not sure i understand the question right, but if you want your app to access the likes of a user, you have to submit your app to facebook. Without review, you only can access public profile and email.

Comment: All I want to do is access the Graph and view recent posts for a particular user using a PHP script.

Comment: You need an Access Token to query the Graph API - including accessing public page posts. If this is all happening Server Side you should just log in once and then create a long lived access token - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#termtokens. If you don't use or require the user_likes permission then you shouldn't ask for it when logging in.